# The precedence of preprocessor operator "defined"?

Tags: c, operators, c-preprocessor

I'm working on a c preprocessor and have found that, since "defined" is a preprocessor-only operator, its precedence level is never listed among the other c operators. Since it is unary and logical, I'd put it on the 2nd level, but...

Does anyone know the exact answer?

Comment: Your mention of a “level” for precedence suggests you are referring to some secondary source. If you are working on a C preprocessor, you ought to be using the C standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C 2018 6.10.1 1 says:

> The expression that controls conditional inclusion shall be an integer constant expression except that… it may contain unary operator expressions of the form “`defined` *identifier*” or “`defined (` *identifier* `)`”… [Note: The text in quotes here is offset display text in the original.]

The phrase “unary operator expression” refers to 6.5.3 (“Unary operators”), a subsection of 6.5 (“Expressions”). Thus, `defined` behaves like any of the other unary operators.

However, note that the operand must be an identifier. It cannot be the general *unary-expression* or *cast-expression* that most normal operators accept. It is those *unary-expression* or *cast-expression* symbols that bring higher-precedence operators into the grammar for unary expressions. This means something like `#if defined x++` is not permitted (even prior to consideration of whether `++` may appear in an integer constant expression), so there is never any other option. “`defined` *identifier*” never appears with any higher-precedence operator adjacent to the identifier.

Answer (score 0):

An `#if` directive is immediately followed by a *constant experssion*.  Any `defined` operators are evaluated **first** before the rest of the constant expression is evaluated.

Section 6.10.1p4 of the C standard states:

> Prior to evaluation, macro invocations in the list of preprocessing
>   tokens that will become the controlling constant expression are
>   replaced (except for those macro names modified by  the defined unary 
>   operator),  just  as  in  normal  text.   If  the  token defined is
>   generated as a result of this replacement process or use of the
>   defined unary operator does not match one of the two specified forms
>   prior to macro replacement, the behavior is undefined.   **After  all 
>   replacements**  due  to  macro  expansion  **and  the defined unary
>   operator**   have   been   performed,   all   remaining   identifiers
>   (including   those   lexically identical  to  keywords)  are  replaced
>   with  the  pp-number 0 , and  then  each  preprocessing token  is 
>   converted  into  a  token.   **The resulting  tokens  compose  the 
>   controlling  constant expression  which  is  evaluated  according  to 
>   the  rules  of  6.6.**
>   ...

The references section 6.6 dictates the semantics of Constant Expressions